# Best format for Python documentation example code

Tags: discussion, documentation

I wanted to ask this question with regard to documentation while it is still young and there is the opportunity to convert everything to and establish a standard format.

For code examples, often you want to show the value of a variable. There are, in reality, several ways to do this. I will list a few below (in Python):

1.

```
>>> x = 1
>>> x += 1  # x == 2
```

2.

```
>>> x = 1
>>> print(x + 1)  # 2
```

3.

```
>>> x = 1
>>> print(x + 1)
2
```

4.

```
>>> x = 1
>>> x + 1  # 2
```

5.

```
>>> x = 1
>>> x + 1
2
```

Of course, I understand that 3 and 5 only make sense within the context of the Python interpreter, thus requiring the leading `>>>` for clarity, and perhaps even though that was once discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310839/should-i-prefix-example-python-code-with-to-indicate-running-in-the-interp), it may warrant another discussion now that there is a Stack Overflow documentation.

Though this is just a small example, I believe it represents a larger issue.

If the goal of Stack Overflow documentation is to provide better documentation then what is out there, then we must consider that documentation is often less than comprehensive for the same reason it is often consistent: it is often written and maintained by one person or a small team.

As the large and diverse community that Stack Overflow is, I think it is important that we set some standards for the way examples should be presented in the documentation for the sake of consistency, which I hope many of you agree is important, if not critical, for a user using said documentation.

**Side-note**: I wanted to create a new tag called `documentation-examples`, but I don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: Actually, i had the same question. Thanks for asking :)

Comment: When writing answers I tend to put large chunks of code (class definitions, for example) as you'd see them in a source file (which you haven't included at all), then examples of usage as you'd see them in the interpreter (5, or sometimes 3). Mostly because that's the easiest way for me to set them up; write the big bits in a file, then import it and interactively demonstrate what happens. But also it helps the reader; they can copy multiline chunks directly, then the interactive parts show context, action and reaction.

Comment: Also, note there already seems to be an effort to establish this *within Documentation*: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/394/python-documentation-guidelines

Comment: Nice going Python community. @jonrsharpe, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: [Direct link to last version of the direct copy vs interpreter example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/31793) before it and topic were deleted

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I only know a tiny bit about Python, but my advice applies to all languages:

> Use whatever style is most helpful to someone trying to **learn or relearn the topic**.

Generally, that implies:

- simple rather than complex
- commented rather than bare
- direct rather than roundabout
- modern rather than outdated
- self-contained rather than incomplete
- minimal rather than expansive

There's significant overlap to [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), of course. But there's also an added burden of actually illustrating the topic in some way.

To go back to your suggestions, don't use an example specific to the interpreter unless the interpreter is what you are illustrating. Consider using comments if they help explain the topic and aren't redundant. If the goal is to show how `print()` works, don't remove that function call. Don't use the `+=` notation if that might confuse the reader.

In other words, don't worry about a standard style so much as trying to communicate to the reader. It require thought and a little empathy, not rules that limit.

Comment: Of course communicating to the reader is the most important thing, but what about consistency of documentation?

Comment: Consistency is great, but we don't actually expect most readers to read more than one or two topics at a time. Most people will land on the page via Google, read enough of the examples to know how to proceed and start coding. (I've done this with SO answers many a time.) Maybe if we learn people are reading whole tag we might want to think about consistency.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you for your input on the matter.

Comment: You're an adherent to the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) and you didn't even know it. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think adhering to option `5` following [pep-0257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) in writing Python documentation would be really helpful, and it's a shame to not adhere to that standard while [the official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) does. Having different standards can be confusing for readers.

The fact that the [introduction](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/193/introduction-to-python#t=201609062345121474425) currently includes `$` characters to indicate a command line prompt but doesn't adhere to `pep-0257` is a shame and at times confusing. For example: the [syntax section](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/93078) includes

```
 ' '.join(['stack', 'overflow']) ==> 'stack overflow'
```

which uses a `==>` to show what that the code to the left of the `==>` generates the string to the right, but the example itself is not valid Python code. This confusingly reminds me of R, where `b <- 'a'` stores  the string `a` in variable `b` (and that is valid code).

Just like the standard Python documentation, the [R Wikipedia examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)) are usefully preceded with a `>` to indicate a prompt. Comments preceeded by `#` (just like Python comments and highlighted accordingly) and lines without a `>` after prompt lines indicate output from the command on the previous line.

```
 > x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)   # Create ordered collection (vector)
 > y <- x^2              # Square the elements of x
 > print(y)              # print (vector) y
 [1]  1  4  9 16 25 36
```

Multi-line sections without `>` intuitively are read as a full file (or 'script') of code without being confused with a command line environment.

```
install.packages("caTools")  # install external package
library(caTools)             # external package providing write.gif function
jet.colors <- colorRampPalette(c("green", "blue", "red", "cyan", "#7FFF7F",
                                 "yellow", "#FF7F00", "red", "#7F0000"))
m <- 1000                    # define size
```

Thankfully the [current StackOverflow first R documentation page](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/360/introduction-to-r#t=201609071200553996538) use that formatting as well.

It is perhaps a function of the annoyance of typing `>>>` rather than a single character (like for R) that has fostered this frustration for Python documentation specifically. This [guidelines discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/394/python-documentation-guidelines) has been removed, apparently in part for the annoyance of failed copying of `>>>` from bits of code, and for the reasons mentioned in the accepted answer to this question.

I'm not suggesting all code examples should be based on prompts but—as the [Python documentation does](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/stdlib2.html#output-formatting)—using `>>>` to indicate what is a prompt versus examples without a prompt usefully differentiate to the reader what each code example is for. It seems a shame to shy away from that here and as ericmarkmartin suggested that has further implications for documentation of other interpreted languages ([R](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/360/introduction-to-r#t=201609071200553996538) and [Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ruby/195/introduction-to-ruby#t=201609070056324631169) to name but 2).